# Is there a table that lists which Visual Studio version comes with which version of clang-format?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang-format

I have been using the clang-format that comes with Visual Studio. Previously the clang-format version that Visual Studio brought with it was 9.x. Now after some time and some Visual Studio updates, I have noticed that the clang-format version was updated to 10. I wonder if there is any information online that shows which version of Visual Studio comes with which version of clang-format. I have not found any resources on that topic, except [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/) article that indicates, that clang-format coming bundeled with Visual Studio was added in the 2017 version with clang-format version 5.

Any information on this topic is appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no document about the version correspondence between clang-format and VS, except that the article mentioned a little.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you can specify a custom clang-format.exe if you want a specific version. Options/Text Editor/CC++/Formatting/General/Use custom clang-format.exe file